# Rock Paper Scissor Game Using Java

Tags: java

Ok so i made a java program which you input either stone paper or scissor from the user and then the computer will generate a random choice and accordingly print the results. The program logic (i mean about the comparison of the user's and opponents choice) is working fine . I set up a do - while loop in such a way that is the user enters 'Y' then there would be a second match and this would go on until the user terminates the loop . But, i get the error "Cannot Find Symbol : Variable ans"

So can anyone please explain me why do i get this error and how to fix it ?

Here's the code :

import java.lang.Math;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class STP

```
 {      
      public static void main (String args[])
             {
                 do {
                 String c , ans ;

                    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
                    System.out.println("Stone , Paper or Scissor ?");
                    System.out.println("Press s for stone , p for paper and sc for scissor ");
                    System.out.println("Enter Your Choice");
                    c=in.nextLine();
                              int max,min=0;
                              int rand = 0;
                              max=3;
                              min=1;
                              rand= min +(int)(Math.random() * ((max-min)+1));
                              System.out.println("Rand = " + rand);

                                     switch(c)
                                       {
                                       case "s" :
                                       if (rand==1){
                                         System.out.println("User's Choice : Stone");
                                         System.out.println("Opponent's Choice : Stone");
                                         System.out.println("Draw!"); } 

                                      else if (rand==2){
                                         System.out.println("User's Choice : Stone");
                                         System.out.println("Opponent's Choice : Paper");
                                         System.out.println("Opponent Wins!"); } 

                                       else if (rand ==3){
                                         System.out.println("User's Choice : Stone");
                                         System.out.println("Opponent's Choice : Scissor");
                                         System.out.println("User Wins!"); } 
                                         break;

                                               case "p":
                                               if (rand==1){
                                                 System.out.println("User's Choice : Paper");
                                                 System.out.println("Opponent's Choice : Stone");
                                                 System.out.println("User Wins!");}

                                              else if (rand  ==2){
                                                 System.out.println("User's Choice : Paper");
                                                 System.out.println("Opponent's Choice : Paper");
                                                 System.out.println("Draw!");}  

                                              else if (rand == 3){
                                                 System.out.println("User's Choice : Paper");
                                                 System.out.println("Opponent's Choice : Scissor");
                                                 System.out.println("Opponent Wins!!");}
                                                 break;
                                                      case "sc":
                                                      if (rand==1){
                                                         System.out.println("User's Choice : Scissor");
                                                         System.out.println("Opponent's Choice : Stone");
                                                         System.out.println("Opponent Wins!!");}

                                                      else if (rand==2){
                                                          System.out.println("User's Choice : Scissor");
                                                          System.out.println("Opponent's Choice : Paper");
                                                          System.out.println("User Wins!");}

                                                       else if (rand==3){
                                                           System.out.println("User's Choice : Scissor");
                                                           System.out.println("Opponent's Choice : Scissor");
                                                           System.out.println("Draw!!");}
                                                       break;
                                                          }
                                     System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                                     System.out.println("Do you want to play again ? ");
                                     System.out.println("Enter 'Y' for Yes and 'N' for No");
                                     ans = in.nextLine();
                                                       }
                                     while (ans =="Y");                  
                                                    }
                                                }
```

Comment: If you just formatted your code properly, you wouldn't have needed to ask.

Comment: writing everything as one big function inside main does not reflect Java philosophy at all. consider create a base class "Unit" (for example) , then inherit this class into "Stone", "Paper" etc, and creating a public method "winner(Unit unit)" that returns the winner . this is just an example for object oriented design

Comment: Umm actually i,m just a 13 year old teenager and i started learning java on my own three months back .........

Comment: I do not have that much experience or practice to use various objects and classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ans` must be declared prior to the while loop in order to be in scope for the loop's condition. You should also change your String comparison from == to equals.

```
             String ans = "";
             do {
                 String c;
                 ...
             } while (ans.equals("Y"));
```

Comment: Thanks A Lot Man ! Completely Solved My Problem ! A very big thanks to you !